# Restful client without using maven

Tags: spring-mvc

i'm trying to create a restful client with Spring MVC framework. I want to receive xml files from a specific url, and print it in the screen. I saw many tutorials, which are using Maven dependencies etc. Is it possible to create a RESTfull web service without using Maven? Does anyone knows a good tutorial to propose? I am new in web technologies but i personally believe that the implementation of the REST web service is quite annoying and difficult as well when the Spring framework is used. Does anyone has an idea about other java web frameworks that can make REST client services easier?

Comment: Maven handles the dependencies, not the actual service.  Find the applicable jars separately from their vendor websites and add them directly to your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache HTTP client libraries

http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

just put the required jars in the application classpath.

[This tutorial](http://www.alexanderinteractive.com/blog/2011/04/simple-java-rest-client-with-commons-htttpclient/) will help you to start using it: